# best way to plot two datasets against each other, which are together in a long format

Tags: r, plot

I think this is best explain with an example. Assume I have 6 couples man and woman and each of 12 people has a certain salary, as shown in a data.frame below

```
xx <- data.frame (gender = c(rep("man", 6), rep("woman", 6)), 
                  couple = c(1:6, 1:6), 
                  salary = c(1:6, seq (2, 12, 2)))

xx <- xx[sample (1:nrow(xx)), ]
```

The data is randomised. I need to plot the salary of each man against each woman WITHIN a couple. I know how to do this using basic functionality, but I want to learn smth a bit more elegant, perhaps ggplot2 has such functionality, but I cant figure out a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be like this

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(xx,aes(x=couple,y=salary,fill=gender))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

You could also try `x=factor(couple)` in the `aes` statement - which will label each couple.

[image]

Comment: this is a good solution, but I need a scatterplot, since I have thousands of points